# Permission Error while trying to delete Facebook Page Rating Response through GraphAPI

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am using the Facebook GraphAPI for deleting a Review response that I had previously posted through the same API.

The API works fine when I Create or Update the Review response. but it fails and throws a permission error when I try to delete it.

response is something like this.

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#200) Permissions error",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 200,
    "fbtrace_id": "A17mQ_ohj6C7BUqNSdVrXjX"
  }
}
```

I tried this through the Facebook GraphAPI explorer and python code as well but nothing works. Same error occurs.

[the image of the API call through Facebook GraphAPI explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gl7Yq.png)

I tried Researching myself but as far as I know this API doesn't work. I found this bug report on developer.facebook.com but it also shows that it was never fixed.
https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/1831406020315773/?join_id=f2b67c94316afa